# Skipping CUDA's EULA

Tags: kubuntu, cuda

When installing CUDA on Kubuntu 15.10, i.e. running `sudo sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run`,  how can I skip CUDA's EULA? Right now I have to scroll down for one minute.

I don't want to use `sudo sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run -silent` either because I need to see the error messages or warnings that the script may output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>SPACE</kbd> performs a page jump, so it makes going through the CUDA's EULA much faster (a few seconds).

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

if you press `q` you directly go to the end

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the runfile(local) installer from this location

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Here's how to accept the EULA silently and provide what you want to install.

e.g. toolkit, driver or samples.

```
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.3.1/local_installers/cuda_12.3.1_545.23.08_linux.run

sudo sh cuda_12.3.1_545.23.08_linux.run --silent --toolkit --driver --samples
```